# How to get rid of "Compiling" message stuck on mode line?

Tags: mode-line

For some reason it's always showing Compiling, even if there is no compilation.

*I found the answer, I post this question to record the solution for it*

Comment: The answer you provided is *NOT* correct: it might alleviate the symptom of the message in the mode line, but if the variable is not nil, you need to investigate the reason for that. See my comments below the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set `compilation-in-progress` to `nil`  to get rid of it:

```
(setq compilation-in-progress nil)
```

Comment: You should not have to touch the variable at all. If it was non-nil, then some compilation process that emacs started might still be running.  The value of the variable is the list of such processes, so you should make sure that those processes are dead. That should set the value of the variable to nil without your mucking around with it. Setting the variable to nil does not do anything about the processes, so you might still have them running and chewing up resources.

Comment: BTW, since you cannot get to them through the variable any more, you should do a `ps -edalf` to find any such processes and kill them if necessary - or reboot.

Comment: Why not just M-x list-processes? I did that and there was no running process, so it was a bug that the compilation message stayed there, wasn't it?

Comment: Is this in the same session of emacs where you had the problem? Or did you restart emacs?

Comment: And in any case, you did not mention any investigation you did about what processes were running, either in the question or in the answer. You should at least add that information to the answer. And if there are no processes but the variable is not nil, then that is a bug and should be reported with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.